# For an NFA, can we always find a RAM?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, computability, finite-automata, discrete-mathematics

For an NFA, can we always find a RAM, which recognises the same language?

Comment: What does "RAM" mean here? RAM-model Turing machine? That would make the question very trivial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If RAM is a [Random Access Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) (i.e., a rudimentary computer with registers, memory and assorted instructions), the answer is just "build a DFA that recognizes the same language, simulate that DFA in code". I.e., have a transition table that tells you the next state for each combination of state and input symbol; start in the start state, check if the state after consuming all input is final.

More abstractly: RAM is equivalent in computing power to a Turing machine. As regular languages are decidable, they can be decided by a (deterministic) Turing machine or a RAM.